# Making a note in a .bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

At the top of my Bibliography page (before the authors are cited), I want to make the following note:

*Note: The online-only journals cited in this paper do not have page numbers*

Do I write this in my .bib file?

Comment: No. That sort of thing should go between the header of the bibliography and the contents it self. Thus you will probably have to redefine the `thebibliography` environment. Some classes have ready build features for this, but alas you did not provide a minimal example showing us what kind of document you are writing.

Comment: I'm using the natbib package, and using a custom template for my thesis. I have my main Thesis tex. document, which does the layout etc. and then I insert the chapters, bibliography from the different folders:

\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}  
\bibliography{Bibliography}  
\end{document}

Comment: Please update your question with the code instead of adding it in a comment. Since you are using `natbib` you could just redefine `\bibpreamble` with your comment.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as an answer so the item can be closed.

Since the OP use the `natbib` package, a comment above the bibliography can be added via

```
\renewcommand\bibpreamble{Here is my note}
```